# EV3 program refuses to work

Tags: ev3

I downloaded a 67KB program into my EV3 block. However, the program refuses to work. The EV3 says "Main", the name of my program, but it does not respond otherwise. What is the problem, and how do I fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: Where did you download the program from?  A URL would be nice.  Does your EV3 work with other programs normally?

Comment: Can you please send a screenshot of the program if you can see it? On Windows 10, using Win+Shift+S will allow you to crop out a part of your screen and save it as an image. You can then add the image here

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a wait block in front of the program and at the back. :)